# Generate N amount of outputs depending on input. Python

Tags: python, function, operating-system, output

```
import os,random

def randomizer(input,sample_size,output='NM_controls.xls'):

#Input file with query

    query=open(input,'r').read().split('\n')
    dir,file=os.path.split(input)    
    temp = os.path.join(dir,output)    
    out_file=open(temp,'w')

    name_list = 833 #### got this from input

    output_amount = (name_list)/(sample_size) #### = 3.6 but I want the floor value so its fine
```

---

i'm writing a function right now and the number of outputs depends on the input.  so in my function , it takes in a file and then scans it and partitions the names and other data.

the next part mutually-exclusive and randomly samples from this lists.  i want it to generate a certain amount of files but that depends on how many names are in the list.

**is there anyway to use the 'os' module to create a certain number of lists that i did not specify in variables ?**

in this case it would be 3 outputs ['output_1.txt','output_2.txt','output_3.txt']

****sorry for the confusion! so i'm using the OS module because I want to create non-existent files in the same directory that the input file was located.  that is the only way i know how to do it

Comment: its not very clear what you are asking ...

Comment: What is "use the 'os' module" part of your question?

Comment: Also, normally, the way to "create multiple Foo", no matter what Foo is, is to create a `list` or other collection, and a loop where you create one Foo and add it to the list (or, more simply, use a list comprehension to do it all in one step).

Comment: You can simply call `open` with the 'w' flag to create a new file. No need to use `os`.

Comment: Please modify your question to make it clear that you are asking about writing to `n` files (as noted in your comment on my answer) so that the question and answers may be useful to others

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write to `output_amount` files (as indicated by `the out_file` variable), then the following should work.

```
for n in range(output_amount):
    outfile = open('%s_%d.txt'%(temp, n), 'w')
    # Now write the data to output file n
```

If you want to create a list with `n` items, see abarnert's answer.

Comment: Well, he wants to "create a certain number of lists", and this won't do that… but it will "create a certain number of files", and considering how confusing the question is, maybe that's close-ish…

Comment: @abarnert - Yeah I assumed, from the little that I understood, that the OP was then processing each list element independently (as they don't show a list being created anyway) and saving the output, in which case they may as well just loop over the number of files instead of creating the list

Comment: this is what i was looking for but i'm confused on how to get this to work... so i want to write to out_file1, out_file2, and out_file3 .... so this makes it so i can write to temp_1 and so on ?

Comment: @draconisthe0ry - No, `temp` is a variable that holds the root filename as in your code.  E.g. if temp is '/home/user/thisfile' the output would write to '/home/user/thisfile_1.txt', '/home/user/thisfile_2.txt', etc

Comment: @draconisthe0ry - See here http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations for general string formatting in python (which is what I used)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "create a certain number of lists" (where that number isn't known until runtime), that's easy:

```
my_lists = []
for _ in range(certain_number):
    my_lists.append(make_another_list())
```

Or, even more simply:

```
my_lists = [make_another_list() for _ in range(certain_number)]
```

Or, if you have a dynamic number of input lists, and want to create one output list for each, you don't even need to calculate the number:

```
my_lists = [transform_a_list(input_list) for input_list in input_lists]
```

And obviously, there is nothing list-specific here. As you can tell, my other than the word `list` appearing in the names of the `make_another_list` and `transform_a_list` functions, I'm not making any use of the fact that the things you're creating a certain number of are lists. You can create a certain number of strings, numbers, arrays, threads, files, databases, etc. the same way.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that we've covered both the list generation and n-file output in our answers - maybe the answer is some combination of the two ;)

Comment: @mutzmatron: Yeah, that's what I was aiming for… or, if not actually being the answer, maybe between us we've written enough for the OP to say, "No, that's not what I meant, and neither is that, _this_ is" (where "this" is something we can answer).